# Java: constructor and argument list error

Tags: java

I have this problem :

I am trying to compile this :

```
public class Agora extends CreditCardPayment {

public void run() {

CashPayment ad1 = new CashPayment(12f);
ad1.paymentDetails();

CashPayment ad2 = new CashPayment(156.4f);
ad2.paymentDetails();

int cardnum1 = 1253462136;
CreditCardPayment ad3 = new CreditCardPayment(325.99f , "Visa" , "12/1/2015" , cardnum1);
ad3.paymentDetails();

int cardnum2 = 1235623151;
CreditCardPayment ad4 = new CreditCardPayment(999.99f , "Master" , "25/6/2016" , cardnum2);
ad4.paymentDetails();
 }
}
```

but it keeps giving me this error :

Agora.java:3: error: constructor CreditCardPayment in class CreditCardPayment cannot
be applied to given types;
public class Agora extends CreditCardPayment {

required: float,String,String,int
 found: no arguments
 reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

And this is the CreditCardPayment class :

```
public class CreditCardPayment extends Payment{

public CreditCardPayment(float x ,String name , String exp_date , int card_num) {
 super (x);
 Card_name = name;
 Expiration_date = exp_date;
 Card_number = card_num;
 }

public String paymentDetails() {
  return super.paymentDetails() + "Card's name :" + Card_name + " , Expiration Date :" + Expiration_date + " , Card Number :" + Card_number ;
  }

  private String Card_name;
  private String Expiration_date;
  private int Card_number;
  }
```

I am a computer science student and don't know much yet so please excuse me if this is just a silly mistake but I can't find it. Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Try recompiling the classes.

Comment: Inheritance is a `is-a` relationship. When you create a `Agora` it also must create a `CreditCardPayment`. Since you need to pass arguments to the `CreditCardPayment` constructor, you need to use `super()` similar to how it is used in `CreditCardPayment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @clcto's comment: Java provides a no-argument default constructor for classes *unless* you specify one or more other constructors. You have provided constructors for `CreditCardPayment`, so there is no no-arg constructor for this class.

You have *not* provided constructors for `Agora`, so the default behaviour is to assume a no-arg constructor, as if you had written

```
public Agora() {
    super();
}
```

But there is no no-arg constructor for the superclass (`CreditCardPayment`), so this fails.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you are creating your `Agora` class as a subclass of `CreditCardPayment`.  Because you haven't supplied a constructor for `Agora`, the default constructor is supplied by the compiler, which attempts to call the default constructor for the superclass, `CreditCardPayment()`.  But no such constructor exists; the only constructor for `CreditCardPayment` takes 4 parameters.  That explains the compiler error.

Your `Agora` class seems to use `CreditCardPayment`; it is not itself a `CreditCardPayment`.  The relationship is "uses", not "is a".  `Agora` uses `CreditCardPayment`, but `Agora` isn't a `CreditCardPayment`.

I would remove the `extends CreditCardPayment` clause on your `Agora` class definition; it's not needed and it shouldn't be there.

```
public class Agora {
```